# Syntax error in List.Sort method call

Tags: c#

I am getting an error in this line "syntax error'=>' expected"

```
ListOfPossiblePlates.Sort((OnePlate ,OtherPlate) OtherPlate.strChars.Length.CompareTo(OnePlate.strChars.Length));
```

please tell me the solution any one

Answer (score 0):

You should write it this way;

```
ListOfPossiblePlates.Sort((OnePlate ,OtherPlate) => OtherPlate.strChars.Length.CompareTo(OnePlate.strChars.Length));
```